# Is the makefile generated by CMake giving me a False Positive?

Tags: c++, boost, makefile, cmake

It appears the make generated by CMake is not including my *.cpp files in the compilation process. I have a deliberate typo in one of the *.cpp files and that is not showing up as an error in the compilation step. The associated header is included in app.cpp in the app folder. I have the following setup for my CMake files from the top-level folder of the project:

```
├── app
│   ├── app.cpp
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Doxyfile
├── Makefile
├── source
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── hardware
│   │   ├── cansocket.cpp
│   │   ├── cansocket.hpp
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── gpiobase.hpp
│   │   ├── gpiofactory.cpp
│   │   ├── gpiofactory.hpp
│   │   ├── gpioinput.cpp
│   │   ├── gpioinput.hpp
│   │   ├── gpiooutput.cpp
│   │   ├── gpiooutput.hpp
│   │   ├── hardwaredevicebase.hpp
│   │   ├── led.cpp
│   │   ├── led.hpp
│   │   ├── pwm.cpp
│   │   ├── pwm.hpp
│   │   ├── serial.cpp
│   │   └── serial.hpp
│   └── software
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── encodersmonitor.cpp
│       ├── encodersmonitor.hpp
│       ├── utils.cpp
│       └── utils.hpp
├── test
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── test.cpp
└── toolchain.cmake
```

My top-level CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# Project name and a few useful settings. Other commands can pick up the results
project(Xmbed
    VERSION 1.0
    DESCRIPTION "Embedded C/C++ project with the Beaglebone Black (BBB)"
    LANGUAGES C CXX)

option(BUILD_FOR_TEST "Build the test application" OFF)

SET (BOOST_MIN_VERSION "1.71.0")
set (Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)

if(BUILD_FOR_TEST)
    set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "/home/bdn/Programming/boost-1.71.0-amd64/include")
    set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR "/home/bdn/Programming/boost-1.71.0-amd64/lib")
else()
    set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR "/home/bdn/Programming/boost-1.71.0-armv7/include")
    set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR "/home/bdn/Programming/boost-1.71.0-armv7/lib")
endif()

set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
set(BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK ON)

find_package(Threads)

if(BUILD_FOR_TEST)
    find_package(Boost 1.71.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread system chrono)
else()
    find_package(Boost 1.71.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread system chrono program_options)
endif()

if(BUILD_FOR_TEST)
    enable_testing()
    include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} "/home/bdn/Programming/gtest/include")
    link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR} "/home/bdn/Programming/gtest/lib")
else()
    include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
endif()

add_subdirectory(source)

if(BUILD_FOR_TEST)
    add_subdirectory(test)
else()
    add_subdirectory(app)
endif()
```

source/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(hardware)
add_subdirectory(software)
```

source/hardware/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set( HEADERS
     ${HEADERS}
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cansocket.hpp
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gpiobase.hpp
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gpiofactory.hpp
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gpioinput.hpp
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gpiooutput.hpp
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/hardwaredevicebase.hpp
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/led.hpp
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/pwm.hpp
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/serial.hpp
     PARENT_SCOPE
     )

set( SOURCES
     ${SOURCES}
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cansocket.cpp
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gpiofactory.cpp
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gpioinput.cpp
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gpiooutput.cpp
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/led.cpp
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/pwm.cpp
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/serial.cpp
     PARENT_SCOPE
     )
```

source/software/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set( HEADERS
     ${HEADERS}
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/encodersmonitor.hpp
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/utils.hpp
     PARENT_SCOPE
     )

set( SOURCES
     ${SOURCES}
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/encodersmonitor.cpp
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/utils.cpp
     PARENT_SCOPE
     )
```

app/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(xmbed_app app.cpp ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(xmbed_app PUBLIC "../source/hardware")
target_include_directories(xmbed_app PUBLIC "../source/software")
target_link_libraries(xmbed_app INTERFACE Boost::thread Boost::chrono Boost::system Boost::program_options)
set_target_properties(xmbed_app PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
add_custom_command(TARGET xmbed_app POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_STRIP} xmbed_app)
```

I am not quite astute in CMake, but I feel close but not quite close. Is there some other way to include the sources?

Comment: "I have a deliberate typo in one of the ***.cpp** files" - May be, `.h` file instead? Because later you say "The **associated header** is included in app.cpp in the app folder." Anywhere, you may check whether build log contains `app.cpp` file or not. If build log contains the file and it is compiled successfully, then the file is correct.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem? Which files are not appearing in the compilation step? What is the typo? Can you provide the code for `app.cpp` to show *how* you are include the headers?